# How can I add a control (like an icon) to a DataGridTextColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to add an icon to a `DataGridTextColumn` cell, so that it appears next to the `TextBox`. I know I could use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` to do this, but I lose all the benefits of a `DataGridTextColumn`. For example, a `DataGridTextColumn` enters edit mode as soon as I start typing, and knows that pressing Esc should restore the original value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow why you don't want to use `DataGridTemplateColumn`, but you also have the option of making a custom class derived from `DataGridBoundColumn` and overriding `GenerateElement` and `GenerateEditingElement`. If you're using auto-generated columns you'll also need to handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event to create your custom `DataGridBoundColumn` when appropriate for the particular column you want to use it for.

But again, I think AnjumSKhan is right, the `DataGridTemplateColumn` should be adequate for your needs if all you want to do is show an image next to the text box. The only time I've ever needed to go with a custom `DataGridBoundColumn` is when I needed special behavior that I just couldn't accomplish easily through a XAML template. Those situations are few and far between.

Edit:
On the issue of the cell not going into Edit Mode when you click on it, I actually faced a similar issue when using a custom `DataGridCell` template. This worked for me (put it in your `DataGrid`'s resources):

```
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGridCell}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
            <EventSetter Event="Control.GotFocus" Handler="DataGridCell_GotFocus"/>            
    </Style>
```

and then in the handler `DataGridCell_GotFocus`:

```
    private void DataGridCell_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this._MyDataGrid.BeginEdit();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter, I may need to derive from DataGridBoundColumn to do what I want, and copy a lot of the code from the DataGridTextColumn source code. As I said in my comment to AnjumSKhan, the DataGridTemplateColumn doesn't allow me to start typing on the selected cell to automatically start editing the TextBox. I need to double-click on the cell in order to put it in edit mode, and that's not what I want.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't try to replicate that but I'm not surprised because I faced something similar. See my edit above for how I handled it. Hopefully it'll work for you too rather than having to re-invent a lot of logic.

Comment: This is close to what I want but not quite. I don't actually want it to go into edit mode when I click on the cell. I want it to go into edit mode when I start typing on the current cell. Then, if I press Escape, I want it to undo what I typed and restore the original text that was there. Your solution may be useful to me in the future, though, so thank you.

Comment: Oh, I actually like that behavior even better. Sorry I wasn't paying close attention to what you were saying. Sounds like you want to capture the PreviewKeyDown event then. What if you went the DataGridTemplateColumn route but attached an event handler to the PreviewKeyDownEvent of the TextBlock in the normal CellTemplate? I haven't tried it but if it works that should be a lot easier than trying to make a derived DataGridColumn.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

1. `DataGridTemplateColumn` are provided when you want full customization.
2. Provide both `CellTemplate` and `CellEditingTemplate`. eg;

   ```
     <DataGridTemplateColumn>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                   <Image Source="..."/>
                 </StackPanel>  
             </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                   <Image Source="..."/>
                 </StackPanel>
              </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   ```

And you get your `Escape` key functionality here too.

Comment: Thanks, AnjumSKhan, but I already tried this and it doesn't do what I want. I want to be able to click once on a cell, and start typing to immediately edit the TextBox (just like DataGridTextColumn). Also, pressing the Escape key while typing restores the original text. With the DataGridTemplateColumn, I need to double-click on the cell first, and pressing Escape does not restore the original text.